# Cannot install windows from flash drive on new hard disc

Tags: windows

I installed a new hard disc on my old desk top, then i formatted a USB flash drive with FAT32 an put an  bootable win10 installation on the flash drive. I tested it on another pc, and I works..

In my BIOS i have CD-ROM as first Boot, its not possible to boot directly from USB flash drive.

The motherboard is a fc gigabyte ga-945p-s3.

The installation stops after the PC device listing, where the cursor just continue the blink.

I tried to boot from all the different possiblities.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change boot type in your BIOS to USB flash drive?
Impossible if you cant change this boot setting to USB

Comment: My options are these: Floppy
LS120
Hard disk
CD ROM
ZIP
USB-FDD
USB-ZIP
USB-CDROM
USB-HDD
LAN

Comment: If i change the boot to USB-FDD, i get the following message: Boot from CD/DVD: Boot from CD/DVD: invalid partition table:

Comment: No one can help me?